# Как загрузить картинки Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с загрузкой картинок в разные кнопки.Заранее благодарен.
Пытался так,но картинка загружается только в постер:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]').send_keys('images/imge/piv.jpg')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]').send_keys('images/imge/pivo.jpg')
```

[image: Poster и Bigposter кнопки]
[image: Poster HTML]
[image: Bigposter HTML]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ты посмотрел, какая именно картинка загружается в poster? уверен вторая.

метод find_element возвращает первый найденный в дереве элемент. и поиск идет сверху вниз. если первый раз по пути `//input[@type="file"]` тебе вернулся poster, то и второй раз тоже он вернется.

Решение - конкретизировать Xpath.

Например: xpath поддерживает индексацию. (и кажется она начинается с 1)

- `//input[@type="file"][1]` - вернет poster
- `//input[@type="file"][2]` - вернет big_poster

**А еще лучше** опереться на другие критерии поиска. В данном случае у обоих элементов прописан id. ID уникален (не всегда) и позволяет точно найти нужный элемент.

Comment: Да,картинка в poster загружалкась 1,потом 2.    Попробовал  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"][1]').send_keys(
                                '/home/alex/projects/allprojects/all/adder_project/images/imge/piv.jpg')
                            time.sleep(6)
                            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"][2]').send_keys(
                                '/home/alex/projects/allprojects/all/adder_project/images/imge/pivo.jpg')

Comment: Первая картинка по первому элементу загружается,по второму элементу не загружается: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type="file"][2]"}   .Буду думать про id.Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: find_element(By.ID, 'id')

Comment: Прошёл по всем id в bigposter ,но ничего не загрузилось

Comment: по всем id? вот по этому пройдись https://file.io/a526qLBI4t5z

Comment: driver.find_element(By.ID, 'upload_button_big-poster').send_keys(
                            '/home/alex/projects/allprojects/all/adder_project/images/imge/pivo.jpg')

Comment: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.77)

Comment: Спасибо за ваше время и помощь,я нашёл решение.

Comment: element not interactable, нашел же!

Comment: а для спасибо кнопка есть. и выложи решение

Comment: Поблагодарил,ещё раз вам спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]')[
                        0].send_keys('/home/alex/projects/allprojects/all/adder_project/images/imge/piv.jpg')
                    time.sleep(6)
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]')[
                        1].send_keys('/home/alex/projects/allprojects/all/adder_project/images/imge/pivo.jpg')
                    time.sleep(6)
```

Этот код работает для 2 форм загрузки,нужно было делать через

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]')[
                        0]
```

и менять елемент [0] ....[1]